# Calibre: difference between print to PDF and conver to PDF

Tags: pdf, epub, calibre

I'm trying to convert an EPUB/AZW3 to PDF.

And there're 2 options

### 1. Print to PDF from the side bar of book view

[image]

[image]

There are only a few options, but the rendering is very good (without unncessary page breaks)

### 2. Conver to PDF

[image]

It gives many options. However, it also produces uncessary page breaks.

---

**What I want**: I want to use option to print PDF, I only need to change the font size smaller, how can I do it?

Thanks!

FYI, the differences of page break between 2 approachces

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For changing the font while converting to PDF you need to use "Convert to PDF",
where in the sections "Look & feel" and "PDF output" you can set the sizes of fonts:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

For more information see the article
[Turning an epub into an attractive PDF](https://dumplingcart.org/2016/converting-epubs-to-an-attractive-pdf-in-calibre/).

Comment: but the problem using this approach is that it generate too many page breaks. Is it possible to compare the options set by both approaches? So I can find out how the page breaks are generated.

Comment: I have used this procedure many times and never had any page breaks at all - it just generates one continuous PDF. It might have to do with your specific AZW3. If you can post it somewhere I'll have a look.